# Synchronize threads using two queues

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

Assume that I have a pool of threads. This pool of threads uses two queues `q1` and `q2`. It reads from `q1` and writes new items on `q2`. When `q1` is empty, we swap the two queues `q1, q2, = q2, q1` and we repeat the process until both are empty. In order to synchonize the threads, I use another queue which contains only one item and I remove this item at the end of the process.

I think this is a very stupid way to do it. Any suggestion for improvement?

A very nice simple example is on the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.join) but with only one queue. My solution does not look very nice, if it is correct:

```
global flag
global lock
global barrier
global q1
global q2
global q
while True:
    if q1.empty():
        flag = False
        barrier.wait() # wait for all the theads to reach this point.
        # execute the code of swapping queues only once
        with lock:
            if not flag:
                flag = True
                if q2.empty():
                    q.get()
                    q.task_done()
                else:
                    q1, q2 = q2, q1

    process_items_in_q1()
```

Comment: Any reason you are using 2 input queues?  If you have a pool of worker threads, why not have one input queue the workers get work from?  First in first out?  Is the double input queue a requirement?

Comment: I am implementing BFS + some stuff with each node that we discover. Each phase of seaching can be parallelized, but when one level is finished, only then we can move to the next one. Unless, of course, there is a better idea that I miss.

Answer (score 0):

I think your aproach works.  Here are two others that you may or may not find better:

1. you can use only one queue and push N markers to separate the "levels", where N is the number of threads.  When a thread reads a marker it just calls barrier.wait().  This should be enough if the goal is just to ensure that all N threads call barrier.wait() between the levels.
2. or alternatively, you can simplify a bit the code posted above: use 2 plain lists instead of 2 queues.  All threads pop from `list1` and append to `list2`, which doesn't need the special care in the logic of Queue.  Also, if the "levels" are each relatively large, you might simply repeat for each level the whole code that creates threads and waits until they are all done.  This would make the one-level-at-a-time logic even more obvious.

(Finally, as usual, note that so far you don't gain any processing power by using threads in Python: there's the GIL.)

Comment: Thanks for the input!
the alternative solution with the markers should be equivalent. My best guess is that the queue mechanism with the task_done abstracts the barriers. I have not looked it up though.
As for the lists, they implement inefficiently the `pop()` operation. As for GIL, my process_items is I/O bound so threads are OK.

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity: I had in mind `list1.pop()` with no argument, i.e. pop the last element of the list (which is efficient).  If needed you can `reverse()` the list once when it is moved from `list1` to `list2`.  Or use `collection.deque`.